# php -> send file to remote -> remote execute -> remote sends file back

Tags: php, exec

How can i do this?

User loads a page. Uploads a file. File has to be send to remote server. Remote server executes series of commands. Remote server sends file back.

**EDIT:**

I need to copy file from shared hosting server to VPS box. I managed to login via ssh without passwords from both servers. How to copy file to remote server via ssh? I'm using rsync/cron for syncing/backup some folders but i don't think rsync is not a good idea for this. need another idea.

Comment: have you looked into sockets? http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php

Comment: I think there must be an easier way :)

Comment: is the remote server a web server at all? more info about servers and your access would be nice

Comment: remote is a vps ubuntu 10.10 LAMP server. local server is a shared CentOS server.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cURL to upload a file from this server to another. E.g. [like it is done here](http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html)

Comment: I added this link http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html

Comment: Thank you. I'll check that :)